# SQLite Autoincrement reset sorting By varchar column

Tags: database, sqlite, auto-increment

I filled up a database, and i want to reset the numeric autoincrement id, but I want to do leave it in the same order that I get by retrieving the items in the table sorting them by a particular varchar (text) value column.

I know there's tons of questions like this, but i haven´t found any that does it like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert from a select statement with something like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
  new_table (col_a, col_b)
SELECT 
  col_a, 
  col_b
FROM old_table
ORDER BY 
  col_b
```